# Upgrade Optaplanner from 7 to 8 report an error

Tags: optaplanner

I use accumulate(drools) with inline custom code correctly in Optaplanner 7.33.0,but get a error() in 8.4.1. The error is "Legacy accumulate can be used only with drools-mvel on classpath".

I am not familiar with Drools
and
I failed to find a solution here：
https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/upgradeRecipe8.html

Comment: I believe `drools-mvel` first became optional and later got removed. Can you paste that custom code? Maybe we just need to add a migration step on how to change that legacy accumulate into a modern accumulate.

Comment: In order to be able to understand your issue better, I'd like to see:
- The DRL. Feel free to take out all the rules but the one that's giving you trouble.
- Your dependencies. Ideally a Maven dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`), or something of the like.